# Spring Security error in displaying custom page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working on Spring Security Integration,
My application with inbuilt security page works fine.
But for custom login page its giving error

```
The localhost page isn’t working
```

Here is my code for reference

inside spring-security.xml

```
  <http use-expressions="true">
      >

        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/> <!-- this means all URL in this app will be checked if user is authenticated -->

            <form-login
            login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />


        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/"/> <!-- the logout url we will use in JSP -->
    </http>
```

In login.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Custom Login Page</title>
</head>
<body onload='document.loginForm.j_username.focus();'>
<h3>Custom Login Page</h3>

<%

String errorString = (String)request.getAttribute("error");
if(errorString != null && errorString.trim().equals("true")){
out.println("Incorrect login name or password. Please retry using correct login name and password.");
}
%>

<form name='loginForm' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />"
method='POST'>

<table>
<tr>
<td>User:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='j_username' value=''>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input type='password' name='j_password' />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input name="submit" type="submit"
value="submit" />
</td>
<td><input name="reset" type="reset" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login(ModelMap mode,
            @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
            @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {
        System.out.println("\n\t -------------");
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("login");

        if (error != null) {
            model.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
        }

        if (logout != null) {
            model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
        }
        return model;

    }
```

---

When I run project using in built form pulgin, the url is

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringMvcSecurity/spring_security_login
```

and after login if I manually hit the url

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringMvcSecurity/login
```

It shows me the login page
But I don't if the page displays this time then why it is not displaying in custom configuration.
Please help.

Thanks shazin
there are 4 changes

> 1. Need to change the url name in RequestMapping url for ex:customlogin
> 2. same name need to replace in spring-security.xml
> 3. add line in spring-security.xml
> 4. replace the username password attribute names, the way those appears in jsp page.

`<intercept-url pattern="/customlogin" access="permitAll" />`

Comment: Please explain the problem you have. Does it return 404? Or Exception?

Comment: shazin its shows neither exception nor 404 its displays message saying, localhost redirected you too many times..that's it. thanks for your reply

Comment: please do not post the solution in your question. Write a new answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
shazin its shows neither exception nor 404 its displays message saying, localhost redirected you too many times..that's it. thanks for your reply
```

That is because you have your `@RequestMapping` value and .jsp name as `login`. Change at least one like the following.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/customlogin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login(ModelMap mode,
            @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
            @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {
        System.out.println("\n\t -------------");
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("login");

        if (error != null) {
            model.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
        }

        if (logout != null) {
            model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
        }
        return model;

    }
```

And in your configuration

```
<http pattern="/customlogin*" security="none"/>
<http use-expressions="true">
      >
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/> <!-- this means all URL in this app will be checked if user is authenticated -->

            <form-login
            login-page="/customlogin"
            default-target-url="/"
            authentication-failure-url="/customlogin?error"
            username-parameter="j_username"
            password-parameter="j_password" />


        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/"/> <!-- the logout url we will use in JSP -->
    </http>
```

Comment: Shazin after adding the below line its started working
        <intercept-url pattern="/customlogin" access="permitAll" /> Please edit  your answer adding this line and also changing the j_username and j_password in security.xml

Comment: Updated. Instead of <intercept-url pattern="/customlogin" access="permitAll" /> use <http pattern="/customlogin*" security="none"/>